# Trying to create a filled dataframe from pandas crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot-table

I've got a numpy array that looks like this, in general (it was created from a [pd crosstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74312955/grouping-by-a-key-and-creating-a-separate-column-for-each-associated-value) if that's of any significance)

| Person | 1to1 Person Attribute | Circumstance | Outcome A Count | Outcome B Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 | 1 | X | 100 | 25 |
| DEF2 | 2 | X | 1 | 2 |
|  |  | Y | 0 | 2 |
| XYZ1 | 1 | X | 33 | 5 |
|  |  | Y | 5 | 10 |

that I'd like to turn into a pandas dataframe that looks like

| Person | 1to1 Person Attribute | Circumstance | Outcome A Count | Outcome B Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 | 1 | X | 100 | 25 |
| DEF2 | 2 | X | 1 | 2 |
| DEF2 | 2 | Y | 0 | 2 |
| XYZ1 | 1 | X | 33 | 5 |
| XYZ1 | 1 | Y | 5 | 10 |

I've attempted some for loops to take any situation where there's a blank and replace it with the previously observed value, but I've hit such an array of errors I've decided I might be headed down the wrong path entirely.

Thank you, everybody

Comment: Usually, after `pd.crosstab`, one only needs to add `.reset_index()` for getting what you want.

Comment: thank you! i left off my parantheses which, for reasons i'll hopefully come to understand, did not throw an error but also did not accomplish the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.DataFrame(your ndarray).fillna(method = 'ffill')
```